# Start a process from a bound wpf hyperlink

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

What's a simple way to have a WPF Hyperlink run a `Process.Start` on its (data-bound) text content?

Answer (score 0):

One way (that could be improved by refactoring into a UserControl or static class or ValueConverter or ...) is to have the Hyperlink bound to a command on the ViewModel and pass in the content of the Hyperlink (I couldn't find a way to do a relative binding) as the command parameter.

*WPF snippet*

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:ViewModel />
    </TextBlock.DataContext>
    <Hyperlink Command="{Binding LaunchHyperlinkCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_content, Path=Text}">
    <Run Text="{Binding FilePath, Mode=OneWay}" Name="_content"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

*C# DataContext class snippet (Note: using [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/))*

```
public class ViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    public string FilePath { get; private set; }

    public DelegateCommand<string> LaunchHyperlinkCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        LaunchHyperlinkCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(LaunchHyperlink);
    }

    private static void LaunchHyperlink(string link)
    {
        try
        {
            Process.Start(link);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```